# Does intersection of connected closed sets preserve connectedness?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a compact, Hausdorff space, and $\mathcal{A}=\{A_\alpha\}$ be a class of connected, closed subsets that forms a totally ordered set as in inclusion relation. I am trying to prove $\tilde{A}=\bigcap_{\alpha}A_\alpha$ is connected.

So here's what I thought. Suppose $\tilde{A}$ is not connected, which means $\exists f:\tilde{A}\rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ that is a continuous surjection. Since $X$ is compact and Hausdorff therefore normal $(T_4)$, $f$ can be expanded to be a continuous $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow [-1,1]\ s.t.\tilde{f}|_{\tilde{A}}=f$.

From here I made two attempts:

First, from each $A_\alpha$, I could pick a $x_\alpha\in A_\alpha$ forming a net. I wanted to prove $\{f(x_\alpha)\}$ somehow converges to both $-1$ and $1$, which leads to contradiction, but it didn't seem to work.

Second, by connectedness $\tilde{f}(A_\alpha)=[-1,1],\ \forall\alpha$, and if I could show $\tilde{f}(\bigcap A_\alpha)=\bigcap f(A_\alpha)$ then the proof would be complete. Yet usually $f$ needs to be injective to satisfy the equation, so I was wondering if $\{A_\alpha\}$ being a totally ordered set would be useful.

Any hint or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $\tilde{A}$ is disconnected, let $\mathcal{U}_1$ and $\mathcal{U}_2$ be disjoint open sets, covering $\tilde{A}$, each of which intersect $\tilde{A}$. Then, for each $\alpha$, consider $A_\alpha \setminus (\mathcal{U}_1 \cup \mathcal{U}_2)$.

Let me know if you want a further hint.

Comment: I think I have got the point, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll denote the intersection by $A=\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$.

Suppose $A$ is disconnected, so that $A \subseteq U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are disjoint open in $X$ and $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $V \cap A \neq \emptyset$ (as remarked in a comment, this uses normality of $X$ (which follows from compact Hausdorff)).

Then for each $i \in I$, $A_i \nsubseteq U \cup V$, or $\{U,V\}$ would disconnect $A_i$. So $F_i:= A_i \setminus (U \cup V)$ is closed (closed minus open) and non-empty in $X$. As the $A_i$ are linearly ordered by inclusion, the same holds for the sets $\{F_i, i \in I\}$ (we just substract a fixed set). In particular, the $F_i$ have the [f.i.p](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) and as $X$ is compact, there is a point $x \in \bigcap_i F_i \subseteq A$. But $x \notin U \cup V$ by construction, which is a contradiction to how we chose  $U$ and $V$, so $A$ is connected.

Comment: Much appreciated, this is quite a brilliant proof.

Comment: So is it correct to say X doesn't need to be Hausdorff?

Comment: @RodH It does need Hausdorff in a subtle way. A compact $T_1$ counterexample exist. It's used in how I can choose $U$ and $V$ disjoint in $X$ by normality.

Comment: Oh I get it, $(U\cap A)\cap (V\cap A)$ is empty but $U\cap V$ might not be. You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like your first idea can be made to work. Each $A_\alpha$ is connected, and $\{-1,1\}\subseteq\tilde f[A_\alpha]$, so it must be the case that $\tilde f[A_\alpha]=[-1,1]$, and there is a point $x_\alpha\in A_\alpha$ such that $\tilde f(x_\alpha)=0$.

Now let $I=\{\alpha:A_\alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$, and for $\alpha,\beta\in I$ let $\alpha\preceq\beta$ iff $A_\alpha\supseteq A_\beta$. $\langle I,\preceq\rangle$ is a directed set, and the net $\langle x_\alpha:\alpha\in I\rangle$ has a cluster point $x\in X$. Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$; for each $\alpha\in I$ there is a $\beta\in I$ such that $\alpha\preceq\beta$ and $x_\beta\in U$, so $U\cap A_\alpha\supseteq U\cap A_\beta\ne\varnothing$, and therefore $x\in\operatorname{cl}A_\alpha=A_\alpha$. It follows that $x\in\tilde A$, but this is impossible, since clearly $f(x)=\tilde f(x)=0$.

Comment: So that’s what I missed...much appreciated!

Comment: @RodH: You’re welcome!